# Show request duration in drf-spectacular (Swagger)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, elapsedtime, drf-spectacular

I have a Django/DRF project with `drf-spectacular` (Swagger) integration and wondering how can I add a request duration as shown on the image below. Is there any way to achive elapsed time section? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a Swagger-UI feature independent of drf-spectacular. To pass it through simply set the setting like so:

```py
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    "SWAGGER_UI_SETTINGS": {
        "displayRequestDuration": True,
        # other swagger settings
    },
    # other spectcular settings
}
```

other swagger settings can be found [here](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/)

Comment: The case is that it does not help. I tried to add this settings, but there is no "Request Duration" section in final schema.

Comment: It doesn't work in error (4xx) requests though. Because of that I failed to see anything when I installed it before maybe.

Comment: that would most likely be a feature/bug request for swagger-ui. spectacular simply passes through the additional options.